# Does the gradient function at a point give the direction of greatest increase and also perpendicular at the same time?

Tags: calculus

So say if I have a cone and took the gradient and then evaluated it at a point would this vector that points in the direction of greatest increase also be perpendicular and is this true for all surfaces and points?

Very confused here thanks.

Comment: Perpendicular to what?

Comment: Perpendicular to the surface at that point.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing is that the surface must be a surface of constant $f(x,y,z)$

for a surface defined by $f(x,y,z) = m$

we have that $\vec \nabla f(x,y,z)$ is perpendicular to that surface where ever $(x,y,z)$ satisfies $f(x,y,z) = m$.

This makes sense because when you move along a surface of constant $f$ , the value of $f$ obviously doesn't change , so the directional derivative of $f$ in every direction on the surface must vanish, so every direction vector on the surface must be perpendicular to $\vec \nabla f$

it makes no sense to take the gradient of a cone, you must take the gradient of some function $f$ for which the cone is a surface of constant $f$

for a cone with an opening angle of $45^o$ ($z^2=x^2+y^2$), the surface could be defined as 
$$ f(x,y,z)=0 \text{ where }f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2  $$

this is not unique, the same cone could be represented as 
$$ g(x,y,z)=1 \text{ where }g(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2+y^2}{z^2}  $$

the gradients of these functions are not the same, but they are both perpendicular to the surface of the cone when evaluated at any point of the surface of the cone.